# From Dbf to numpy array

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, numpy-ndarray, dbf

**How can I convert a dbf to numpy array without using arcpy?**

I tried using the *dbf* library, but I didn't figure out how to select specific columns from my *dbf* to build the adequate *numpy array*.

**Here is the script I want to reproduce without using arcpy:**

```py
arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(inTable ,("PROVINCE","ZONE_CODE","MEAN", "Datetime","Time"))
arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(str(x[3]),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Using this command lines, I am able to chose the colums I want and then sort them chronologically (that's the aim of my program).

**Here is the one I made with the *dbf* lib:**

```py
arr = dbf.Table(inTable)
arr.open()
arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(str(x[7]),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

I don't know how to select the columns I want, and it just lasts an eternity to compile and sort.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that `arr` is not the same between your code snippets -- in the first it is a numpy `array`, and in the second it's a dbf `Table`.

To get what you want:

```
import dbf
import numpy

table = dbf.Table('some_table.dbf')
table.open()

arr = numpy.array([
    (r.province, r.zone_code, r.mean, r.datetime, r.time)
    for r in table
    ])
arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(str(x[3]).strip(),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

I'm not sure what the difference will be in performance.

---

Disclosure: I am the author of the [`dbf`](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/) package.

Comment: Oh thank you so much dear Mr Furman, I am very pleased and honored. I'll try it and give you the feedback.

Comment: I am sorry, I have an error of unconverted data:

  File "C:\Users\fassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])

ValueError: unconverted data remains

I'll try to resolve it and report you the results.
Thanks again =)

Comment: It's me again, sorry I went back to my code, and I found out that actually, it doesn't work that well. The numpy array returns only the fields names. I've tried to write a new script in order to append all data in the numpy array: 
`table = dbf.Table(inTable).open()
 l= len(table)
 k = 0
 ta = []
 while k<l:
    arr = np.array([table[k][0],table[k][1],table[k][4],table[k][6],table[k][10]])
    ta.append(arr)
    k += 1
print ta
arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(str(x[3]).strip(),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
` I've got an error

Comment: I've got my numpy array (so that answers the question) but I have an error in sorting:
The error traceback: 
`ValueError: time data 'L' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
` 
The 'L' seems bizarre

Comment: It's all right now, that was just a stupid mistake I had. The correct script is bellow:
`table = dbf.Table(inTable).open()
 l= len(table)
 k = 0
 ta = []
 while k<l:
     arr = np.array([table[k][0],table[k][1],table[k][4],table[k][6],table[k][10]])
     ta.append(arr)
     k += 1
 
 arr = sorted(ta,key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(str(x[3]).strip(),"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))`
It works very well